# Excel name is incorrect when opening in ie

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I am trying to open a excel sheet from my application. I call the below method from my page. But when the excel opens it is not having the file name that I am expecting(testExcel) instead it is having the file name as openExcel

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/openExcel.do")
protected void openExcel(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){
    String reportName = "testExcel.xls";
    String reportPath = "C:\reports\";
    String contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel";
    resp.setHeader("ContentType", contentType);
    resp.setContentType(contentType);
    ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
    resp.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + reportName);
    String pragma="no-cache";
    resp.setHeader("Pragma",pragma);
    fileStr = new FileInputStream(new File(reportPath.trim()
                    + reportName.trim()));

    bis = new BufferedInputStream(fileStr);

    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out);

    int len = fileStr.available();
    byte[] buff = new byte[len];

    int retValue=fileStr.read(buff);

    resp.getOutputStream().write(buff);
    resp.getOutputStream().flush();
    resp.getOutputStream().close();
}
```

When I change the below line

```
resp.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + reportName);
```

to

```
resp.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportName);
```

it is working fine and name of the excel is displayed correctly. But the save as pop up does not appear in ie 11 and I get that open or save option in the ie11 footer. I need that message in popup and I need to know why content-disposition: inline is not showing the name correctly. Please help.

Comment: I doubt you can do much about it in Java. Do you know if it's even possible?

Comment: @Kayaman yes this code is working fine in different application. Excel is opening with proper name and pop up is also coming.

Comment: Well, it seems to match the [spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266). What about other browsers?

Comment: Same problem! Any solutions?